# How to use SQL server time data type?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using SQL server time data type, I have made an sp which returns records from that table,
But its throwing exception

```
'Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible''
```

I have checked  the InnerException and its saying

```
 'Input String was not in correct format'
```

When I run my query on SQL server its running fine
below is the structure of my table

```
Id bigint
Name varchar(100)
timefrom time(0)
timeto time(0)
```

below is my sp

```
  SELECT * FROM Table1 where condition
```

I am using NHibernate for data access

```
public System.Collections.IList GetData(long id)
        {
            string connectionStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FNHConnection"].ConnectionString;
            IDbConnection conn;
            conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStr);
            conn.Open();
            ISessionFactory sessionFactor = HibernateTemplate.SessionFactory;
            ISession session = sessionFactor.OpenSession(conn);

            var result = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec dbo.gen_GetData ?")
                .SetParameter(0, id)
            .List();

            return result;
        }
```

its throwing exception on

var result = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec dbo.gen_GetData ?")
                .SetParameter(0, id)
            .List();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find the solution from the below link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx 
One more link, that can be useful:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/usisvde/archive/2007/11/14/time-for-ado-net.aspx